# A frustum is made by removing a small cone from a large cone as shown in the diagram.

Tags: geometry

[this the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oljxe.png)

can someone give me a step by step answer and explanation on how to do this question

Comment: hint: use substraction and similarity

Comment: What Jorge means is 1) calculate the radius of the small cone 2) The volume of the frustum is equal to the volume of the big cone minus the volume of the small cone. 3) Transform volume to mass using density

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculate the mass of the big cone first.

It is $m=\frac{6^2\cdot\pi\cdot 15\cdot2.5}{3}$.

The proportion between the big cone and small one is $\frac{1}{3}$ so the mass of the small cone is $m\cdot (\frac{1}{3})^3$

Finally, your answer is $m(1-(\frac{1}{3})^3)$

Comment: The similarity ratio is $1/3$

Comment: Right, thanks.${}$

Comment: why do they say this on the mark scheme then?  (Highlighted is answer) http://imgur.com/a/MQtk9

Comment: If you multiply the acual terms you get approximately $1361.35681656$